# Adding MultiplePointAnnotation In MapView ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

Im trying to load annotation point into `mapview` in which i have the seperate array for latitude and a seperate array for longitude here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

delegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

delegate.arrForLat=[[NSMutablearray alloc]initwithobjects:@"33.930216",@"33.939788",@"33.9272",@"33.902237"];

delegate.arrForLon=[[NSMutablearray alloc]initwithobjects:@"-118.050392",@"-118.076549",@"-118.065817",@"-118.081733‌​"];

```
     for (int i=0 ; i< delegate.arrForLat.count;i++)
     {
        annotationCoord.latitude = [[delegate.arrForLat objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
        annotationCoord.longitude = [[delegate.arrForLng objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];

        MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
        [MapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
    }

}
```

Now i get only 1 annotation point in `mapview` but i have 4 coordinates.I don't know what mistake i have done.

Comment: Put your full code with loop ?

Comment: ya i have included them

Comment: Is it possible the latitude and longitude values from the delegate are all the same, and thus the annotations are visually overlapped, making it look like there is only one annotation?

Comment: no i zoomed deep into it there is only one annotation point.

Comment: Did my answer help? If so you're supposed to mark it as such so that the next person with this question knows to follow my instructions, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I see it. You only have one `annotationCoord`. On the first trip through the loop you set its lat and long to (33.930216,-118.050392) and create a new object called `annotationPoint` point its `coordinate` attribute to your `annotationCoord`. Then on the next time through the loop you edit `annotationCoord` by giving it new coordinates. But it's still the same `annotationCoord` and the annotation you added to the map is still using it, now with the new coordinates.

So the solution is to make a new CLLocationCoordinate2D each time through the loop.

Comment: These are my latitude and longitude array values  array For Lat--->(
    "33.930216",
    "33.939788",
    "33.9272",
    "33.902237"
)
array For Lng--->(
    " -118.050392",
    " -118.076549",
    " -118.065817",
    "-118.081733"
)

Comment: It would be a lot easier to be sure your data correct if if you put an NSLog statement into your loop and printed out the data as it went through. Otherwise we're seeing what you *want* the data to be, not what the dat actually is.

Comment: ya i printed it but the pin is nothing but the loop's last values..I mean array's last index

Comment: If you are saying that `annotationCoord.latitude` gives the same value every time through the loop then every value in your array is the same and you need to fix that. Please show how your array is populated and maybe edit your code to show how you are printing out the values incase you're not doing what I expected.

Comment: delegate.arrForLat=[[NSMutablearray alloc]initwithobjects:@"33.930216",@"33.939788",@"33.9272",@"33.902237"];                    
delegate.arrForLon=[[NSMutablearray alloc]initwithobjects:@"-118.050392",@"-118.076549",@"-118.065817",@"-118.081733"];

this is my full array

Comment: Code in comments is hard to read. Edit your question above to show where you set your array, how you print out your values in the loop, and the text that gets printed. What I'm trying to establish is that you are correctly looping through all values. You could try a log statment like this:
NSLog(@"i = %d lat = %f",i,[delegate.arrForLat objectAtIndex:i]);

Comment: OK I've changed my suggested answer, see if that helps.

Comment: ya i am getting the correct latitude and longitude values in the looping through 
NSLog

Comment: If the answer is correct you need to mark it as such by selecting the tick box next to it.